# Python remote logging same line

Tags: python, logging

I have  problem with this script, it writes log record to the same line and separate with "#000<15>" or "#000<10>". I think 10 and 15 is the log level, but i want to see it in separate line without "#000<xx>"
How can i achieve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import logging.handlers
import socket
import time
formatterV = logging.Formatter('[%(name)s]-%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = ('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',514),socktype=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
handler.setFormatter(formatterV)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug('this is debug')
logger.debug('this is debug2')
logger.critical('this is critical')
```

Output is:

Oct  6 14:53:09 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  [MyLogger]-DEBUG: this is debug#000<15>[MyLogger]-DEBUG: this is debug2#000<10>[MyLogger]-CRITICAL: this is critical

Comment: the `<15>` and `<10>` is the prio according to the syslog message format: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424#section-6

Comment: its ok, but the problem is other.